# Unable to update "consent status" in apache unomi

Tags: gdprconsentform, apache-unomi

I am having trouble in updating the consent status in Apache Unomi through 
http://localhost:8181/cxs/profiles endpoint.

However, I am able to create new consents at the time of profile creation or update.

The request payload for profile creation is as follows:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8181/cxs/profiles \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic a2FyYWY6a2FyYWY=' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 497' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: e61854e4f21d7dd7f978ad1a3b9ad7b8=a798094d250c6887bf5d0acdf641809a; context-profile-id=7ba87dc1-b39c-481c-8c9a-5238881992ce' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8181' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: e3fc0ce5-2e88-480f-8310-7cf309563adb,a4c96158-804d-4b32-bd4e-2ed905b5cd5e' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{  
   "itemId":"2411426b-fdb5-428d-8f3f-753267bb2c62",
   "itemType":"profile",
   "consents":{  
     "postal/newsletter": {
            "scope": "postal",
            "typeIdentifier": "newsletter",
            "status": "GRANTED",
            "statusDate": "2019-07-28T04:46:38Z",
            "revokeDate": "2023-07-28T04:46:38Z"
        }
   },
   "properties":{  
      "country":"QA",
      "firstname":"Basheer",
      "leadAssignedTo":"XXXXXX",
      "gender":"M",
      "status":1
   }
}'
```

This will return a response as follows :

```
{
    "itemId": "2411426b-fdb5-428d-8f3f-753267bb2c62",
    "itemType": "profile",
    "version": null,
    "properties": {
        "country": "QA",
        "firstname": "Basheer",
        "leadAssignedTo": "XXXXXX",
        "gender": "M",
        "status": 1
    },
    "systemProperties": {},
    "segments": [
        "leads"
    ],
    "scores": {},
    "mergedWith": null,
    "consents": {
        "postal/newsletter": {
            "scope": "postal",
            "typeIdentifier": "newsletter",
            "status": "GRANTED",
            "statusDate": "2019-07-28T04:46:38Z",
            "revokeDate": "2023-07-28T04:46:38Z"
        }
    }
}
```

However, If I try to update the profile and consent using the same endpoint :

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8181/cxs/profiles \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic a2FyYWY6a2FyYWY=' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 502' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: e61854e4f21d7dd7f978ad1a3b9ad7b8=a798094d250c6887bf5d0acdf641809a; context-profile-id=7ba87dc1-b39c-481c-8c9a-5238881992ce' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8181' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 72d712cf-1a53-44a9-aa77-139fb7418509,7054cbf2-e1cb-4bde-9f04-314beb0f4a9f' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{  
   "itemId":"2411426b-fdb5-428d-8f3f-753267bb2c62",
   "itemType":"profile",
   "consents":{  
     "postal/newsletter": {
            "scope": "postal",
            "typeIdentifier": "newsletter",
            "status": "REVOKED",
            "statusDate": "2019-07-28T04:46:38Z",
            "revokeDate": "2019-10-28T04:46:38Z"
        }
   },
   "properties":{  
      "country":"QA",
      "firstname":"Basheer12345",
      "leadAssignedTo":"XXXXXX",
      "gender":"M",
      "status":1
   }
}'
```

The response is as follows :

```
{
    "itemId": "2411426b-fdb5-428d-8f3f-753267bb2c62",
    "itemType": "profile",
    "version": 2,
    "properties": {
        "country": "QA",
        "firstname": "Basheer12345",
        "leadAssignedTo": "XXXXXX",
        "gender": "M",
        "status": 1
    },
    "systemProperties": {},
    "segments": [
        "leads"
    ],
    "scores": {},
    "mergedWith": null,
    "consents": {
        "postal/newsletter": {
            "scope": "postal",
            "typeIdentifier": "newsletter",
            "status": "GRANTED",
            "statusDate": "2019-07-28T04:46:38Z",
            "revokeDate": "2019-10-28T04:46:38Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Here the **firstname**, **revokeDate** has been updated, but the **status** is not updated. What am I doing wrong?

***Why the status is not geting updated?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a UNOMI bug. We have fixed the issue and expecting it to be solved in the newer versions.

[UNOMI-261](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UNOMI-261)